# Why using "eval" in an unrelated part destroys the performance of the rest of my app on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, eval

Mind the following N-Body simulator in JavaScript:

```js
setTimeout(function(){

// returns how many times we managed to call the function in 1 second
function bench(f){ 
    for (var i=0, t=Date.now(); Date.now()<t+1000; ++i) 
        f(); 
    return i; 
};

// This is a buffer of atoms, [a.pos.x, a.pos.y, a.vel.x, a.vel.y, ...]
var atoms = []; 
for (var i=0; i<100; ++i)
    atoms.push(50+Math.random()*100, 50+Math.random()*100, 0, 0);                       

// Compute the next frame and render it.
setInterval(function(){
    main_loop(atoms);
    render_atoms(ctx,atoms);
},1000/60);

// This is the problematic line. Read below.
//eval("(function(a){return a})");

// The main loop computes an attractive force between each pair of atoms.
function main_loop(atoms){
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4)
        for (var j=0; j<atoms.length; j+=4){
            var v0     = atoms[i+0];
            var v1     = atoms[i+1];
            var v2     = atoms[i+2];
            var v3     = atoms[i+3];
            var v4     = atoms[j+0];
            var v5     = atoms[j+1];
            var v6     = atoms[j+2];
            var v7     = atoms[j+3];
            var v51    = (v5-v1)*(v5-v1);
            var v40    = (v4-v0)*(v4-v0);
            var k      = Math.sqrt(v51+v40*v40)>4 ? Math.sqrt(v51+v40) : 4;
            atoms[j+0] = v4;
            atoms[j+1] = v5;
            atoms[j+2] = (v0-v4)/k+v6;
            atoms[j+3] = (v1-v5)/k+v7;
        };
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4){
        var v0     = 0.005;
        var v3     = atoms[i+2];
        var v4     = atoms[i+3];
        atoms[i+0] = (v3*v0)+atoms[i+0];
        atoms[i+1] = (v4*v0)+atoms[i+1];
        atoms[i+2] = v3;
        atoms[i+3] = v4;
    };
};

// This is just a simple circle renderer for the atoms, nevermind it.
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
function render_atoms(ctx,atoms){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(atoms[i],atoms[i+1],1,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
};
  
// This will print how many times we're able to run main_loop in 1 second.
console.log(bench(function(){main_loop(atoms)}));
},100);
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
</body>
```

When you click "run" in this program, it will output in your console how many times it was able to run `main_loop` in one second. On my console, it outputs something around `6466`. Now, see this almost identical program:

```js
setTimeout(function(){

// returns how many times we managed to call the function in 1 second
function bench(f){ 
    for (var i=0, t=Date.now(); Date.now()<t+1000; ++i) 
        f(); 
    return i; 
};

// This is a buffer of atoms, [a.pos.x, a.pos.y, a.vel.x, a.vel.y, ...]
var atoms = []; 
for (var i=0; i<100; ++i)
    atoms.push(50+Math.random()*100, 50+Math.random()*100, 0, 0);                       

// Compute the next frame and render it.
setInterval(function(){
    main_loop(atoms);
    render_atoms(ctx,atoms);
},1000/60);

// This is the problematic line. Read below.
eval("(function(a){return a})");

// The main loop computes an attractive force between each pair of atoms.
function main_loop(atoms){
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4)
        for (var j=0; j<atoms.length; j+=4){
            var v0     = atoms[i+0];
            var v1     = atoms[i+1];
            var v2     = atoms[i+2];
            var v3     = atoms[i+3];
            var v4     = atoms[j+0];
            var v5     = atoms[j+1];
            var v6     = atoms[j+2];
            var v7     = atoms[j+3];
            var v51    = (v5-v1)*(v5-v1);
            var v40    = (v4-v0)*(v4-v0);
            var k      = Math.sqrt(v51+v40*v40)>4 ? Math.sqrt(v51+v40) : 4;
            atoms[j+0] = v4;
            atoms[j+1] = v5;
            atoms[j+2] = (v0-v4)/k+v6;
            atoms[j+3] = (v1-v5)/k+v7;
        };
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4){
        var v0     = 0.005;
        var v3     = atoms[i+2];
        var v4     = atoms[i+3];
        atoms[i+0] = (v3*v0)+atoms[i+0];
        atoms[i+1] = (v4*v0)+atoms[i+1];
        atoms[i+2] = v3;
        atoms[i+3] = v4;
    };
};

// This is just a simple circle renderer for the atoms, nevermind it.
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
function render_atoms(ctx,atoms){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    for (var i=0; i<atoms.length; i+=4){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(atoms[i],atoms[i+1],1,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
};
  
// This will print how many times we're able to run main_loop in 1 second.
console.log(bench(function(){main_loop(atoms)}));
},100);
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
</body>
```

The only difference being that I aded a `eval("(function(a){return a})")` in the middle of nowhere. Running that one, I get a number around 700 on my console. In other words, simply calling eval once caused the execution of my simulation to become 10 times slower forever.

This is happening on Chrome Version 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit), on OSX Yosemite. It doesn't happen on FireFox.

Why?

Comment: Probably because the engine doesn't even try to optimize the code.

Comment: So, having an unrelated eval causes Chrome to not bother optimizing everything else?

Comment: Well, `eval` is in the top level of your script, so I assume V8 deopts the whole block, which contains everything. But other people have a much better understanding of V8 optimization than I do. This is just my assumption.

Comment: This doesn't look like "*middle of nowhere*". It's right there in the part where you measure.

Comment: @Bergi No it isn't, did you misread the code?

Comment: @Nit: It's in the same scope where `atoms` and `main_loop` (and the whole rest) are declared.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but it's never executed when measuring, it's only ever executed once before measuring even begins.

Comment: @Nit: Right, it's not measured itself, but it certainly isn't "*unrelated*".

Comment: I would guess that even if its possible use is tangential and/or unnecessary to the core execution, simply having it as a possibility probably cuts out many possible optimizations; once it sees that "In this script, nothing can ever..." it uses that to shrink code. But, it has no idea what might get modified if `eval()` exists.